How to set an automated action to change Active status of a view on Odoo (v14)
I have created a view which creates a popup on our website. The idea is the show this popup when the company is closed due to the public holidays. I set the public holidays in the calendar and I would like to trigger this view Active status when the date meets with those dates of public holiday.
So, when it is public holiday, automated action would change the Active status from False to True and the popup will be appear on the website. When it is not holiday, it will trigger it again and the status will be False.
Below, you can find the automated action that I have created. I am pretty sure that is doable either with execute python code or with another action but I don't how to achieve this. Any idea?


"Browse" the view and write on active. env["ir.ui.view"].browse(<id>).write({"active": True"}). And you also need the way back by another action setting it to False after the holidays. I'm not sure if your action like above will work that way, but the code should be the same anyway.

Thank you @CZoellner. It works. I'm trying to set an if condition now.
